# Making iframe trasparent doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html5-canvas

I have added an iframe on a client page.

```
<iframe id='the-feedback-form-iframe' src='http://test.com/test.html'  frameborder='0' style='position:fixed; bottom:0; right:0; ' allowtransparency="true"></iframe>
```

test.html page uses a canvas to draw shapes on it, which is acting as an overlay on the client page. 
[image]

once the drawing is done and when the user clicks on "Send" button I need to capture a screen shot. I'm using `canvas.toDataURL("image/png");` to get the image it captures the image successfully but the underneeth parent page content is invisible.

[image]

I tried making the iframe transparent too but couldn't get it to work

Comment: How did you make the iframe transparent?

Comment: @epascarello <iframe allowtransparency="true">